# Converting from for loops to forEach/map/some .. etc

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to not use for loops in the following snippet?

```
const states = [
  { a: 1 },
  { b: 1 },
  { b: 2, c: 1 }
];

const defaultState = {
  a: 0,
  b: 0,
  c: 0
};

const getRange = prop => {
  const range = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < states.length; i += 1) {
    let prevState;

    for (let j = i - 1; j >= 0; j -= 1) {
      prevState = states[j] && states[j][prop];
      if (prevState) break;
    }

    range[i] = states[i][prop] || (prevState || defaultState[prop]);
  }

  return range;
};

getRange('a') // [1, 1, 1]
getRange('b') // [0, 1, 2]
getRange('c') // [0, 0, 1]
```

It should be in JavaScript only without depending on any other libs, I've tried to play a little with forEach() and some(), but couldn't replicate the current behavior. This is for exploration of the language purposes.

Comment: What does this code do?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Every state can have props, every prop can change, props that are not changed should stay the same and not get lost when moving forward to a newer state.

Example:
`State 1: h: 100, w: 100 // output: h: 100, w: 100`
`State 2: h: 200 // output: h: 200, w: 100`
`State 3: w: 200 // output: h: 200, w: 200`

Comment: Never use `.forEach`.

Comment: @Bergi please elaborate, why

Comment: It has no good purpose that couldn't be achieved easier with a `for of` loop. And you'll want to avoid side effects anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const states = [
  { a: 1 },
  { b: 1 },
  { b: 2, c: 1 }
];

const defaultState = {
  a: 0,
  b: 0,
  c: 0
};

const getRange = prop => {
  return states.reduce((res, o, i) => {
    res.push( o[prop] || res[i - 1] || defaultState[prop] );
    return res;
  }, []);
};

console.log(getRange('a')); // [1, 1, 1]
console.log(getRange('b')); // [0, 1, 2]
console.log(getRange('c')); // [0, 0, 1]
```

`res` is the result array. For each object `o` in the `states` array we push:

```
res.push( o[prop] || res[i - 1] || defaultState[prop] );
// or:
res[i] = o[prop] || res[i - 1] || defaultState[prop];
```

either:

- this current object `o` state,
- the previous state recorded (stored in `res[i - 1]`) (the previous state),
- or the default state from `defaultState`.

In my code, `reduce` replaces the outer `for` from your code, `res[i - 1]` replaces the inner `for` (as there is no need to loop until the first element to get the previous state that we already know it's only one step behind).

**EDIT:**

To treat `0`s as thruthy use this:

```
res.push( (o[prop] || o[prop] == 0)? o[prop]:               // if o[prop] is truthy or equal to 0 then use it
          (res[i - 1] || res[i - 1] == 0)? res[i - 1]:      // otherwise (o[prop] is neither truthy nor equal to 0) then if res[i - 1] is truthy or equal to 0 then use res[i - 1]
          defaultState[prop] );                             // otherwise just use the default value no matter whether it is truthy or not (that's the point of default values anyway)
```

or:

```
res.push( !isNaN(o[prop])? o[prop]:                         // if o[prop] is a valid number use it
          !isNaN(res[i - 1])? res[i - 1]:                   // otherwise, if res[i - 1] is a valid number then use it
          defaultState[prop] );                             // otherwise, use the default value
```

Comment: @slim I was explaining as you were posting this comment.

Comment: The output seems on point, does this check "all" prev states to see if the prop is present in any of them?

Comment: @user5470921 each step is looking for the previous state, so there is no need to loop, we just have to check one step behind. Two steps behind had already been checked by the previous iteration.

Comment: Tested it with various scenarios, works as intended.

Comment: I omitted the extra return for the record `const getRange = prop => states.reduce(...)`.

Comment: @user5470921 yeah better!

Comment: @user5470921 I hope you understood my explanation of the `res[i - 1]` bit. If you still haven't please let me know.

Comment: Just finished reading reduce()'s docs, yep got it, we are checking as we move. You gotta love js.

Comment: I added the following piece to force treating zeros as truthy, wondering if you can provide any further optmz on it.
`let propValue = defaultState[prop];

[res[i - 1], o[prop]].forEach(possibleValue => {
  if (possibleValue) propValue = possibleValue;
  else if (possibleValue === 0) propValue = 0;
});

res.push(propValue);`
instead of `res.push(o[prop] || res[i - 1] || defaultState[prop]);`

Comment: @user5470921 check the **EDIT** section.

Comment: Regarding your edit, better use `prop in o` and `i > 0` for the predicates

Comment: @Bergi The **EDIT** takes care of that (`o[prop]` and `res[i - 1]` will have `undefined` values when `prop` is not `in` `o` and when `i === 0` respectivly).

Comment: Great! the `isNaN` approach won't work because props can be strings too.Thanks.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Yes, exactly that edit. It's a better practice to test the property name to be valid instead of trying to access the property value and checking whether it's `undefined` or not.

Comment: @user5470921 `isNaN` works on strings too: `isNaN("Hello") === true` but `isNaN("5") === false`.

Answer (score 1):

A quite literal translation - every loop becomes a method call - of the code would be

```
const getRange = defaultStats => state => prop => {
  return states.map((state, i) => {
    const prev = state.slice(0, i-1).reverse().find(s => s[prop]);
    return state[prop] || prev[prop] || defaultState[prop];
  });
};
```

Comment: This is a brilliant line `prev = state.slice(0, i-1).reverse().find(s => s[prop])`, haven't tested your solution, chose the other one, I think it's more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const states = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 1 }, { b: 2, c: 1 }];
const defaultState = {a: 0, b: 0, c: 0};

function getRange(prop) {
  let prev;
  return states.map(s =>
      prev = s[prop] || prev || defaultState[prop]);
};

console.log(getRange('a'));
console.log(getRange('b'));
console.log(getRange('c'));
```